# Unable to display Date in JSX in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is my code which is working fine if I initialize test with a string, though if I changed it to `new Date()` its throwing error. Let me know what I am doing wrong as I just started with React.

**Code -**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

    class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            //let test = 'this is a string'; // WORKING FINE
            let test = new Date();
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                    <p>{test}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
```

**Error -**

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Jul 21 2017
>   02:11:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

Comment: `test.toString()`

Comment: @Xotic750 yeah it will work but why I am not able to print it like in old JS days ?

Comment: @Xotic750 and what does this error means - `If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.`

Comment: You cannot print the object because React is trying to render the object as a component. As it is not a string nor a React component, it doesn't know what to do and how to render it.

Comment: `p`'s children must be of type node for JSX, and a date object is not of type node for JSX. I assume that you are talking about when you used HTML and the date gets automajically converted `toString`. But JSX and HTML are not the same thing.

Comment: @Xotic750 awesome...thx for the explanation ..and add this to the answer section so that I can mark it green

Comment: Usually console.log(xxx) is a handy tool when it comes to debugging purposes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing that because Date is an object not a string. To get it to work as you have it with no libraries:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        //let test = 'this is a string'; // WORKING FINE
        let test = new Date();
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>{test.toString()}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Call the toString() method on the date object.

Answer (score 4):

as @Brady Edgar said, you cannot use a Date object into JSX because there is no **string interpolation** between {} but **JSX expressions**. When you use interpolation, like `Today is ${ new Date() }` JS converts the *Date* object to *String* automatically.

What you're doing is using JSX expressions, and `{ new Date() }` returns a *Date* object, and that *is not a valid React child*.

As they already said, you need to convert your *Date* object to *String*. You can use a library such as [*moment*](https://momentjs.com) or just use the method `toLocaleDateString` of *Date* object in order **to use the browser locale**:

```
let test = new Date();
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>{ test.toLocaleDateString() }</p>
  </div>
);
```

I'm sure that you've already solve that, but I wanted to put emphasis on what you are using is not interpolation but JSX expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are passing an object when React is expecting a string. I would recommend working with a package such as [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment). When ever doing date related stuff I find its almost always more efficient to work with a package...and I never say that.

If you are really against having a package then just run `.toString()` on the end of `test`.

```
let test = new Date();
const App = ({}) => (
   <div>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
       <p>{test.toString()}</p>
   </div>
)
```

....Presentational components all the way!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<p>{test.toString()}</p>
```

You're trying to render an object which is not a React component, hence React throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let test = new Date();
const App = ({}) => (
   <div>
       <h1>Today date</h1>
       <p>{test}</p>
   </div>
)
```